# Frequency, if any, of a string with two different thicknesses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string, boundary-conditions, vibrations

Very brief question. Assume a string that is made half out of a thin rope and half out of a thick rope (the thick rope is heavier of course). A transverse mechanical pulse is applied at one end (assume it is very sharp, with all Fourier frequencies in similar amounts). How to calculate how much energy arrives at the other end, compared to a string of uniform thickness.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_coefficient

Comment: I want to better specify my problem. I am buying an old barn, unused for 15+ years. It has columns made of concrete. The builder is afraid that going in and out with the tractor will accelerate collapse (the columns look  good though). I reasoned that any vibration would be transmitted mostly through the column resonance frequency. I figured that doubling the lower part of the column would miminimze transmission but wanted to get an idea of the suppression before buying a lot of concrete.